# Unable to display data using Pig FOREACH

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig, bigdata

I have this smaple dataset in a txt file `(Format: Firstname,Lastname,age,sex)`:

```
(Eric,Ack,27,M)
(Jenny,Dicken,27,F)
(Angs,Dicken,28,M)
(Mahima,Mohanty,29,F)
```

I want to display the `age` and `firstname` of employees having age greater than 27. I am stuck after proceeding quite a bit and looking for some pointers:

I am loading this dataset using:

```
tuple_record = LOAD '~/Documents/Pig_Tuple.txt' AS (details:tuple(firstname:chararray,lastname:chararray,age:int,sex:chararray));
```

Describing gives me this format:

```
describe tuple_record
tuple_record: {details: (firstname: chararray,lastname: chararray,age: int,sex: chararray)}
```

Then I am flattening the record using this:

```
flatten_tuple_record = FOREACH tuple_record GENERATE FLATTEN(details);
```

Describing the flattening gives me this:

```
describe flatten_tuple_record
flatten_tuple_record: {details::firstname: chararray,details::lastname: chararray,details::age: int,details::sex: chararray}
```

Now I want to filter this based on age:

```
filter_by_age = FILTER flatten_tuple_record BY age > 27;
```

Then I am doing a group based on age:

```
group_by_age = GROUP filter_by_age BY age;
```

Now for displaying the firstname and age; I tried this but it did not worked:

```
display_details = FOREACH group_by_age GENERATE group,firstname;
```

Below is the error message:

```
2015-02-01 08:39:37,752 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1025: 
<line 5, column 54> Invalid field projection. Projected field [firstname] does not exist in schema: group:int,filter_by_age:bag{:tuple(details::firstname:chararray,details::lastname:chararray,details::age:int,details::sex:chararray)}
```

Please guide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your pig statements looks good, but after filtering data by age you can directly get the firstname and age as result. Follow the below statements:

```
tuple_record = LOAD '/user/cloudera/Pig_Tuple.txt' AS (details:tuple(firstname:chararray,lastname:chararray,age:int,sex:chararray));

describe tuple_record;

flatten_tuple_record = FOREACH tuple_record GENERATE FLATTEN(details);

describe flatten_tuple_record;

filter_by_age = FILTER flatten_tuple_record BY age > 27;

details = FOREACH filter_by_age GENERATE firstname, age;

dump details;
```

### Update:

Here we can even skip FLATTEN statement:

```
tuple_record = LOAD '/user/cloudera/Pig_Tuple.txt' AS (details:tuple(firstname:chararray,lastname:chararray,age:int,sex:chararray));

describe tuple_record;

filter_by_age = FILTER tuple_record BY details.age > 27;

details = FOREACH filter_by_age GENERATE details.firstname, details.age;

dump details;
```

In both the cases, result will be:

```
(Angs,28)
(Mahima,29)
```

Comment: It seems we dont even need to FLATTEN the data... Please suggest.

Comment: you have to FLATTEN your tuple so that you can access age and other fields in your other pig statements

Comment: Yes its true. But without using `FLATTEN` also I can access it using `details.age`; this is what I meant.

Comment: @user182944 yes, in that case we can skip FLATTEN and we need to use **details.** to refer our properties in the pig statements